# Getting error while build the VisualStudio Cordova application in release mode

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Getting Fatal error while building the Visual-studio Cordova application in release mode.

I'm using Visual-studio 2017 and the Cordova tool-set version - 6.3.1

```
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : [Fatal Error] :3:214: The value of attribute "name" associated with an element type "item" must not contain the '<' character.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Could not read D:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\api\annotations.zip
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : java.io.IOException: Could not parse XML from android/accounts/annotations.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this error by simply removing the Android platform directory, then build, clean the project and build again.

Comment: As stupid as it sounds, this also worked for me. I tried multiple things so I don't remember if `cordova clean android` was enough or if I had to remove android platform and add it again.